# Adding distance between a droplist and its button

Tags: html, css

I have a button which toggles a hidden droplist on hover.
There is no distance between the box and the droplist and that's the issue here.

I wanted to add a little space there within those two by appending margin to the droplist object, but as a result, when I hover a cursor over that space, the hover function triggers back off before it reaches the droplist area.

Here is my code...

```css
/* THE DROPLIST BUTTON */

.droplist {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  float: right;
}

.droplist button {
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #585858;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

.dropcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #393939;
}

.dropcontent a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.droplist:hover button {
  background-color: #333333;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.droplist:hover .dropcontent {
  display: block;
}

.dropcontent a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}


/* THE DROPLIST BUTTON */
```

```html
<div class="droplist" style="margin: 10px; outline: none">
  <button>GAMES</button>
  <div class="dropcontent">
    <a href="#">STICK FIGHT: THE GAME</a>
    <a href="#">CLUSTERTRUCK</a>
    <a href="#">SQUARE BRAWL</a>
    <a href="#">NUCLEAR BUSINESS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add margin-bottom:10px; for button

Comment: why not margin-top:10px; for dropcontent? It works for me?

Comment: @ReadyFreddy by doing this you have a gap that you cannot hover

Comment: Yep i understand now. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add margin to the button instead.

**Why?**

because the dropdown is set to absolute position; thus it won't affect its parent height (`.droplist`) and will be **outside**. Without any margin it's close to the bottom edge of its parent but if you add margin you will make it far and create **a gap outside** of the `.droplist` and you will face the hover issue *(add a border to the container to see it)*.

```css
/* THE DROPLIST BUTTON */

.droplist {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  float: right;
}

.droplist button {
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #585858;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.dropcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #393939;
}

.dropcontent a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.droplist:hover button {
  background-color: #333333;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.droplist:hover .dropcontent {
  display: block;
}

.dropcontent a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}


/* THE DROPLIST BUTTON */
```

```html
<div class="droplist" style="margin: 10px; outline: none">
  <button>GAMES</button>
  <div class="dropcontent">
    <a href="#">STICK FIGHT: THE GAME</a>
    <a href="#">CLUSTERTRUCK</a>
    <a href="#">SQUARE BRAWL</a>
    <a href="#">NUCLEAR BUSINESS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `droplist-hover` to give `padding-bottom:10px` to this div on hover. It will expand droplist div 10 pixels to bottom when you hover on it so `dropcontent` won't close when you move your mouse outside from bottom and also won't open before the mouse inside button. Then you can add `margin-top:10px` to 
`.droplist:hover .dropcontent` to seperate them. Check the snippet.

```css
.droplist {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  float: right;
}

.droplist button {
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #585858;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

.dropcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #393939;
}

.dropcontent a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  min-width: 200px;
}

/*Add this block*/
.droplist:hover{
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

.droplist:hover button {
  background-color: #333333;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

/*Give 10px to margin-top here*/
.droplist:hover .dropcontent {
  margin-top:10px;
  display: block;
}

.dropcontent a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="droplist" style="margin: 10px; outline: none">
  <button>GAMES</button>
  <div class="dropcontent">
    <a href="#">STICK FIGHT: THE GAME</a>
    <a href="#">CLUSTERTRUCK</a>
    <a href="#">SQUARE BRAWL</a>
    <a href="#">NUCLEAR BUSINESS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```